# How to enable AUFS on Debian?

Tags: docker, debian, gitlab-ci

When I try to install docker via:

```
curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh
```

I get the message:

> Warning: current kernel is not supported by the linux-image-extra-virtual package.  We have no AUFS support.  Consider installing the packages linux-image-virtual kernel and linux-image-extra-virtual for AUFS support.

However, neither package seems to exist on Debian Jessie:

```
# apt-get install linux-image-virtual linux-image-extra-virtual
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-image-virtual
E: Unable to locate package linux-image-extra-virtual
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

aufs is not supported by modern kernels, so you should skip to overlayfs from aufs. Just restart your docker daemon with the option:

```
--storage-driver=overlay2
```

(or add this option to /etc/default/docker)

In some systems you should add the processing of the file /etc/default/docker to start procedure by creating /etc/systemd/system/docker.service with content:

```
[Service]
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/docker
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon -H fd:// $OPTIONS \
      $DOCKER_STORAGE_OPTIONS \
      $DOCKER_NETWORK_OPTIONS \
      $BLOCK_REGISTRY \
      $INSECURE_REGISTRY \
      $DOCKER_OPTS
```

More info [here](http://docs.master.dockerproject.org/engine/admin/systemd/#/custom-docker-daemon-options)

Execute

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

for changes to take effect.

**Caution!** All your images become unreachable. If you want to keep them, just save and reload them. You can find the good description [here](http://muehe.org/posts/switching-docker-from-aufs-to-devicemapper/)

UPD. I've changed `overlay` to `overlay2` because it solves a little bit more problem than described [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/selectadriver/)

**UDP**. Not relevant, since `overlay2` used by default in modern version of docker (18-06).

Comment: As of now (January 2017) overlayfs is not considered production ready. Please consult https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/selectadriver/

Comment: @itsafire Can't find info about production readiness on those page.  Could you edit your link adding anchor (#) to the exact chapter?

Comment: I'd added the anchor, but there is none available. Read down to `Future-proofing` or find the text ` `Many people consider OverlayFS as the future...`  There you will find a nice chart with pros and cons of all those device drivers.

Comment: O, now I see, sorry. But the key of my answer is `aufs is not supported by modern kernels` You may say that there is devicemapper, but many people prefer overlay, just google `overlay vs devicemapper`

Comment: The subject of the original question is about aufs and not devicemapper. Even the upcoming debian stretch with kernel 4.8 will have support for aufs by installing it via `apt-get install aufs-dkms`.

Comment: I believe it is better to use modern driver than return to system dropped one.

Comment: It is not dropped. Modern is good. But keeping an eye on recommendations by the manufacturer is also good. Everyone takes his side.

Comment: Sorry, I used an inaccurate  word. As written in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aufs) AUFS was rejected:`aufs was rejected for merging into mainline Linux. Its code was criticized for being "dense, unreadable, and uncommented". Instead, OverlayFS was merged in the Linux kernel.`

Comment: If you had Docker running, you probably had some layers on your machine. When switching to OverlayFS, you have to move away aufs stuff before Docker accepts to start: `service docker stop && umount /var/lib/docker/aufs && mv /var/lib/docker/aufs /var/lib_docker_aufs`

Answer (score 4):

Actually installing a stock jessie gives you a kernel that comes with aufs support. My guess is you upgraded to a higher kernel version through jessie-backports which is not not the standard jessie setup.

This was tested with current Debian jessie 8.7.1 amd64 and kernel 3.16.0.4.

```
# cat /etc/debian_version
8.7
# dpkg --get-selections | grep linux-image
linux-image-3.16.0-4-amd64          install
linux-image-amd64                   install

# dpkg -L linux-image-3.16.0-4-amd64 | grep aufs
/lib/modules/3.16.0-4-amd64/kernel/fs/aufs
/lib/modules/3.16.0-4-amd64/kernel/fs/aufs/aufs.ko
```

So to answer your question:

You could re-install Debian Jessie or down-grade to the default kernel and you have a jessie with aufs support.

For installing aufs on Debian 9 aka Debian stretch one just have to issue an `apt-get install aufs-dkms`. This is sadly not available for jessie-backports at this time.

At our company we are driving our docker hosts with an jessie aufs setup and everything is running flawlessly.

**Update 08-2018**

Even now **I can not recommend overlay2 for production**. We currently have an issue with containers where mysql is not able to create the /var/run/mysqld.sock when running in a container with the overlay2 storage.

This is addressed in this [one year old issue](https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/72) as of August 2018.

Answer (score -2):

You can try

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-extra-$(uname -r)
```

to install an enhanced Kernel version which should contain AUFS support.

Comment: A package like that doesn't seem to exist: https://packages.debian.org/jessie/linux-image-extra

Comment: You are right, I was assuming it is analogous to Ubuntu. What does `uname -a ` tell? And on which infrastructure are you trying to run docker? Some virtualization environments are having problems with the lxc / AUFS business.

Comment: `uname -a` prints `Linux server.name 4.4.8-x86_64-jb1 #1 SMP Thu Apr 21 08:07:36 CEST 2016 x86_64 GNU/Linux`. I'm not quite sure what our provider uses, but the server itself is virtual.

Comment: It seems to be a known thing with Debian Jessie, AUFS is not included in upstream kernels from what I have read. Try `mv /var/lib/docker/aufs /var/lib/docker/aufs_bk` and restart your Docker daemon. Apparently Docker is smart enough to use another filesystem from AUFS. Alternatively you can start the Docker daemon with the --storage-driver parameter to manually specify another.

Comment: Well, it seems like AUFS isn't really required for Docker to function, as the Gitlab CI is now running fine with the Docker executor. I just thought this would be a bit cleaner. Thanks for your efforts!