# docker daemon is not startable

Tags: linux, docker

**Introduction**

Today i had to move from my own virtual server to our companies linux server, where docker version 18.09.2 build 6247962 is installed. The server which provides me the error msgs is an ubuntu 18.04 lts server, my kernel: 4.4.0-042stab141.3

Unfortunately i can not talk to the old admin, because he left the company two years ago

**What i did:**

I need docker for my webcrawler. I’m not sure, if i already got the right image, so tried:

```
sudo docker pull scrapinghub/splash
```

After executing this command i got following error:

```
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.
```

I also tried `chmod 666 /usr/run/docker.sock`, because this was a “solution” i read about on stackoverflow.

When i execute service docker status i get:

```
docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine 
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: start-limit-hit) since Fri 2020-10-23 11:46:30 CEST;   43min ago
Docs: https://docs.docker.com
Process: 7881 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Main PID: 7881 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

Also if i execute `docker ps`, to see my containers, i get:

```
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.39/containers/json: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

when executing as root i get again:

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

I know there are several topics about that error, but none of them helped me, so I am trying it now with my own error messages.

**EDIT**

systemctl status docker:

```
* docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit-hit) since Fri 2020-10-23 14:44:43 CEST; 21min ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 12126 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 12126 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

**dockerd**

```
INFO[2020-10-23T15:16:41.905718923+02:00] libcontainerd: started new docker-containerd process  pid=13326
INFO[2020-10-23T15:16:41.905847880+02:00] parsed scheme: "unix"                         module=grpc
INFO[2020-10-23T15:16:41.905859360+02:00] scheme "unix" not registered, fallback to default scheme  module=grpc
INFO[2020-10-23T15:16:41.905903222+02:00] ccResolverWrapper: sending new addresses to cc: [{unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/docker-containerd.sock 0  <nil>}]  module=grpc
INFO[2020-10-23T15:16:41.905918045+02:00] ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"  module=grpc
INFO[2020-10-23T15:16:41.905969169+02:00] pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc420601340, CONNECTING  module=grpc
INFO[2020-10-23T15:16:41.935402002+02:00] starting containerd                           revision=9754871865f7fe2f4e74d43e2fc7ccd237edcbce version=docker-18.09.2
INFO[2020-10-23T15:16:41.935710291+02:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.content.v1.content"...  type=io.containerd.content.v1
INFO[2020-10-23T15:16:41.935737945+02:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs"...  type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
WARN[2020-10-23T15:16:41.936336356+02:00] failed to load plugin io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs  error="path /var/lib/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs must be a btrfs filesystem to be used with the btrfs snapshotter"
INFO[2020-10-23T15:16:41.936354852+02:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.aufs"...  type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
WARN[2020-10-23T15:16:41.937768910+02:00] failed to load plugin io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.aufs  error="modprobe aufs failed: "modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:514 lookup_builtin_file() could not open builtin file '/lib/modules/4.4.0-042stab141.3/modules.builtin.bin'\nmodprobe: FATAL: Module aufs not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-042stab141.3\n": exit status 1"
INFO[2020-10-23T15:16:41.937790278+02:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.native"...  type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
INFO[2020-10-23T15:16:41.937817682+02:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.overlayfs"...  type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
INFO[2020-10-23T15:16:41.937893773+02:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.zfs"...  type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
WARN[2020-10-23T15:16:41.938518477+02:00] failed to load plugin io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.zfs  error="path /var/lib/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.zfs must be a zfs filesystem to be used with the zfs snapshotter"
INFO[2020-10-23T15:16:41.938534393+02:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.metadata.v1.bolt"...  type=io.containerd.metadata.v1
WARN[2020-10-23T15:16:41.938549461+02:00] could not use snapshotter zfs in metadata plugin  error="path /var/lib/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.zfs must be a zfs filesystem to be used with the zfs snapshotter"
WARN[2020-10-23T15:16:41.938557138+02:00] could not use snapshotter btrfs in metadata plugin  error="path /var/lib/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs must be a btrfs filesystem to be used with the btrfs snapshotter"
WARN[2020-10-23T15:16:41.938565014+02:00] could not use snapshotter aufs in metadata plugin  error="modprobe aufs failed: "modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:514 lookup_builtin_file() could not open builtin file '/lib/modules/4.4.0-042stab141.3/modules.builtin.bin'\nmodprobe: FATAL: Module aufs not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-042stab141.3\n": exit status 1"
INFO[2020-10-23T15:16:41.938661276+02:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.differ.v1.walking"...  type=io.containerd.differ.v1
INFO[2020-10-23T15:16:41.938679507+02:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.gc.v1.scheduler"...  type=io.containerd.gc.v1
INFO[2020-10-23T15:16:41.938717611+02:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.service.v1.containers-service"...  type=io.containerd.service.v1
INFO[2020-10-23T15:16:41.938730440+02:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.service.v1.content-service"...  type=io.containerd.service.v1
INFO[2020-10-23T15:16:41.938744454+02:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.service.v1.diff-service"...  type=io.containerd.service.v1
INFO[2020-10-23T15:16:41.938761110+02:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.service.v1.images-service"...  type=io.containerd.service.v1
INFO[2020-10-23T15:16:41.938772688+02:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.service.v1.leases-service"...  type=io.containerd.service.v1
INFO[2020-10-23T15:16:41.938784541+02:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.service.v1.namespaces-service"...  type=io.containerd.service.v1
INFO[2020-10-23T15:16:41.938796278+02:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.service.v1.snapshots-service"...  type=io.containerd.service.v1
INFO[2020-10-23T15:16:41.938807356+02:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux"...  type=io.containerd.runtime.v1
INFO[2020-10-23T15:16:41.938875766+02:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.runtime.v2.task"...  type=io.containerd.runtime.v2
INFO[2020-10-23T15:16:41.938921789+02:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.monitor.v1.cgroups"...  type=io.containerd.monitor.v1
INFO[2020-10-23T15:16:41.939301371+02:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.service.v1.tasks-service"...  type=io.containerd.service.v1
INFO[2020-10-23T15:16:41.939328814+02:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.internal.v1.restart"...  type=io.containerd.internal.v1
INFO[2020-10-23T15:16:41.939371309+02:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.containers"...  type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
INFO[2020-10-23T15:16:41.939383717+02:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.content"...  type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
INFO[2020-10-23T15:16:41.939395037+02:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.diff"...  type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
INFO[2020-10-23T15:16:41.939405310+02:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.events"...  type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
INFO[2020-10-23T15:16:41.939439881+02:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.healthcheck"...  type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
INFO[2020-10-23T15:16:41.939451270+02:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.images"...  type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
INFO[2020-10-23T15:16:41.939461540+02:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.leases"...  type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
INFO[2020-10-23T15:16:41.939477843+02:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.namespaces"...  type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
INFO[2020-10-23T15:16:41.939488529+02:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.internal.v1.opt"...  type=io.containerd.internal.v1
INFO[2020-10-23T15:16:41.939543415+02:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.snapshots"...  type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
INFO[2020-10-23T15:16:41.939558389+02:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.tasks"...  type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
INFO[2020-10-23T15:16:41.939568889+02:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.version"...  type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
INFO[2020-10-23T15:16:41.939579026+02:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.introspection"...  type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
INFO[2020-10-23T15:16:41.939748944+02:00] serving...                                    address="/var/run/docker/containerd/docker-containerd-debug.sock"
INFO[2020-10-23T15:16:41.939799183+02:00] serving...                                    address="/var/run/docker/containerd/docker-containerd.sock"
INFO[2020-10-23T15:16:41.939810589+02:00] containerd successfully booted in 0.005619s
INFO[2020-10-23T15:16:41.946915966+02:00] pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc420601340, READY  module=grpc
INFO[2020-10-23T15:16:41.950501665+02:00] parsed scheme: "unix"                         module=grpc
INFO[2020-10-23T15:16:41.950522807+02:00] scheme "unix" not registered, fallback to default scheme  module=grpc
INFO[2020-10-23T15:16:41.950564242+02:00] parsed scheme: "unix"                         module=grpc
INFO[2020-10-23T15:16:41.950575481+02:00] scheme "unix" not registered, fallback to default scheme  module=grpc
INFO[2020-10-23T15:16:41.950676109+02:00] ccResolverWrapper: sending new addresses to cc: [{unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/docker-containerd.sock 0  <nil>}]  module=grpc
INFO[2020-10-23T15:16:41.950697518+02:00] ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"  module=grpc
INFO[2020-10-23T15:16:41.950746317+02:00] pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc420601570, CONNECTING  module=grpc
INFO[2020-10-23T15:16:41.950889604+02:00] pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc420601570, READY  module=grpc
INFO[2020-10-23T15:16:41.950962148+02:00] ccResolverWrapper: sending new addresses to cc: [{unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/docker-containerd.sock 0  <nil>}]  module=grpc
INFO[2020-10-23T15:16:41.950978801+02:00] ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"  module=grpc
INFO[2020-10-23T15:16:41.951015340+02:00] pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc420601810, CONNECTING  module=grpc
INFO[2020-10-23T15:16:41.951146523+02:00] pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc420601810, READY  module=grpc
ERRO[2020-10-23T15:16:41.952596133+02:00] 'overlay' not found as a supported filesystem on this host. Please ensure kernel is new enough and has overlay support loaded.  storage-driver=overlay2
ERRO[2020-10-23T15:16:41.953602275+02:00] AUFS was not found in /proc/filesystems       storage-driver=aufs
ERRO[2020-10-23T15:16:41.954528718+02:00] 'overlay' not found as a supported filesystem on this host. Please ensure kernel is new enough and has overlay support loaded.  storage-driver=overlay
INFO[2020-10-23T15:16:41.956786508+02:00] Graph migration to content-addressability took 0.00 seconds
WARN[2020-10-23T15:16:41.958146162+02:00] Your kernel does not support oom control
WARN[2020-10-23T15:16:41.958167327+02:00] Your kernel does not support memory swappiness
WARN[2020-10-23T15:16:41.958182470+02:00] Your kernel does not support kernel memory limit
WARN[2020-10-23T15:16:41.958198841+02:00] Unable to find cpu cgroup in mounts
WARN[2020-10-23T15:16:41.958238330+02:00] Unable to find cpuset cgroup in mounts
WARN[2020-10-23T15:16:41.958309720+02:00] mountpoint for pids not found
INFO[2020-10-23T15:16:41.963433348+02:00] stopping event stream following graceful shutdown  error="context canceled" module=libcontainerd namespace=plugins.moby
INFO[2020-10-23T15:16:41.963543844+02:00] stopping healthcheck following graceful shutdown  module=libcontainerd
INFO[2020-10-23T15:16:41.967297616+02:00] pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc420601810, TRANSIENT_FAILURE  module=grpc
INFO[2020-10-23T15:16:41.967319558+02:00] pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc420601810, CONNECTING  module=grpc
Error starting daemon: Devices cgroup isn't mounted
```

```
-- Logs begin at Fri 2020-10-23 11:03:38 CEST. --
Oct 23 14:44:39 dockerd[12126]: time="2020-10-23T14:44:39.944764478+02:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support memory swappiness"
Oct 23 14:44:39 dockerd[12126]: time="2020-10-23T14:44:39.944777538+02:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support kernel memory limit"
Oct 23 14:44:39 dockerd[12126]: time="2020-10-23T14:44:39.944793390+02:00" level=warning msg="Unable to find cpu cgroup in mounts"
Oct 23 14:44:39 dockerd[12126]: time="2020-10-23T14:44:39.944824929+02:00" level=warning msg="Unable to find cpuset cgroup in mounts"
Oct 23 14:44:39  dockerd[12126]: time="2020-10-23T14:44:39.944869519+02:00" level=warning msg="mountpoint for pids not found"
Oct 23 14:44:39 dockerd[12126]: time="2020-10-23T14:44:39.947106531+02:00" level=info msg="stopping event stream following graceful shutdown" error="context canceled" module=libcontainerd namespace=plugins.moby
Oct 23 14:44:39 dockerd[12126]: time="2020-10-23T14:44:39.947131964+02:00" level=info msg="stopping healthcheck following graceful shutdown" module=libcontainerd
Oct 23 14:44:39 dockerd[12126]: time="2020-10-23T14:44:39.951205781+02:00" level=info msg="pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc42401c7d0, TRANSIENT_FAILURE" module=grpc
Oct 23 14:44:39 dockerd[12126]: time="2020-10-23T14:44:39.951239041+02:00" level=info msg="pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc42401c7d0, CONNECTING" module=grpc
Oct 23 14:44:40 dockerd[12126]: Error starting daemon: Devices cgroup isn't mounted
```

Also if i try docker info i get following error:

````
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?```
````

Comment: What does `journalctl -xe` or `systemctl status docker` say? I had a problem couple of days ago, caused by the default `iptables` changing to `iptables-ntf`.

Comment: Solution for that was btw, `update-alternatives --set iptables /usr/sbin/iptables-legacy`

Comment: i added the output of systemctl status docker

Comment: when running your solution i get: update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for iptables

Comment: Could be that you need to install it, `journalctl -fu docker.service` was the one where I recognized the error. Something like "incompatible operation", sry don't have the logs with me anymore. Nevertheless journal-logs would also be helpful for debugging

Comment: its so frustrating..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223520/discussion-between-y-y-and-moritz-sauter).

Comment: `Devices cgroup isn't mounted` - what linux are you running? What distribution? What services and init manager are you using (systemd/upstart/rc-something)? Could you please post the output of `mount` or `findmnt`?

Answer (score 1):

Since I didn't get a reply to my queries from the chat in the link provided https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223520/discussion-between-y-y-and-moritz-sauter

*Therefore, my answer below has some assumptions.*

It seems you have been using [AUFS](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/aufs-driver/) as the docker storage driver in your "virtual server", which can be confirmed from `docker info` or in the `daemon.json` file usually found in this path `/etc/docker/`.

Given the above is true, when you moved to the new "company Linux server" which has a fairly newer Ubuntu and kernel, therefore there is high possibility that AUFS driver is not enabled by default, you can verify it by `grep aufs /proc/filesystems`.

My introspection comes from your docker logs, it has a warning

`WARN[2020-10-23T15:16:41.937768910+02:00] failed to load plugin io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.aufs  error="modprobe aufs failed: "modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:514 lookup_builtin_file() could not open builtin file '/lib/modules/4.4.0-042stab141.3/modules.builtin.bin'\nmodprobe: FATAL: Module aufs not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-042stab141.3\n": exit status 1"`

Now if all of the above is true how to resolve?
You will probably have to move away from AUFS to overlay2 [check](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38399748/4451944) this answer. Unless you have strict reasons to stick to AUFS, in that case you will have to switch to a different kernel this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41805751/4451944) may help

Note: if you using some non standard kernel or older kernel please do so at your own risk, since there maybe some vulnerabilities which you may have to patch back

Comment: I've read that kernel about 3.10+ were supported, mine is 4.40.62 oder something like that, so I thought it shouldn't rely on that. I talked to my boss and we decided, to move all to my server, so I think my problem is in some way done now. luckily for my headache, bad for my experience

Answer (score 0):

As per all the docker command outputs, it looks like the docker-daemon is down.

You can try to start the docker-daemon using one of the follow commands.

```
$ sudo systemctl start docker
```

or

```
$ sudo service docker start
```

After starting that, your commands will start to work.

And if it is failing, you can reset the limit and restart.

```
sudo systemctl reset-failed docker.service
```

Comment: @Ikamal, thanks for your answer, but those were one of the first things i tried.
```Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.```

Comment: Can you try resetting the failures and retry?

Comment: pardon? what do you mean with failures?

Comment: Please try this `sudo systemctl reset-failed docker.service` then, try to start with `sudo systemctl start docker`